# Change image onclick - Javascript buttons & AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm have a wordpress installation where i have 2x custom fields, that both store images (or rather the urls for the images).

I then have a div that i want to display the images in. but i want to display the first image, then have some nice buttons that will scroll to the next image.

My code so far is below:

```
<div>
        <?php 
        $front_cover = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'front_cover', true);
        $back_cover = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'back_cover', true);
        $artwork = $front_cover;

        if ($back_cover === '') {
            echo '<img src="'.$artwork.'" />';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="'.$artwork.'" />';

        ?>
                    <div class="artwork_controls">
                        <a href="#" class="sliderBtnPrev">Previous</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sliderBtnNext">Next</a>
                        <span class="sliderPagination">1 of 3</span>
                    </div>

        </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see. my If statement checks if the back_cover has any content... if it doesn't it displays the front_cover only.
If the back_cover does have content it should display the front cover and then the buttons that the user clicks to load up the back cover.

My thinking was that i could get the 'previous' and 'next' buttons to dynamically change the $artwork variable, but i don't believe that's possible as the PHP would have already been processed?

This code could be completely wrong, but hopefully you can see what i'm trying to do?

Comment: `if(A) {B} else {B; C}` can be DRY'd to `B; if(!A) C;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
    <?php $front_cover = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'front_cover', true); ?>
    <?php $back_cover = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'back_cover', true); ?>
    <?php $artwork = $front_cover; ?>

    <?php if ($back_cover === '') { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $artwork; ?>" />
    <?php } else { ?>

        <img id="imgA" src="<?php echo $artwork; ?>" />
        <img id="imgB" src="<?php echo $back_cover; ?>" style="display:none;"/>
        <div class="artwork_controls">
            <span class="sliderBtnPrev" onClick="document.getElementById('imgA').style.display='none';document.getElementById('imgB').style.display='';">Show B</span>
            <span class="sliderBtnNext" onClick="document.getElementById('imgB').style.display='none';document.getElementById('imgA').style.display='';">Show A</span>
        </div>


    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do AJAX calls and fetch images upon clicking the "Previous" and "Next" buttons.
However you can just put all your images in the final html and do all the rest with javascript and some css.

So if you just put the two images in the html, lets say they have ids "front-image" and "back-image" so you've got this

```
<img id="front-image" src="imgs/front-cover.jpg"/>
<img id="back-image" src="imgs/back-cover.jpg" style="visiblity: hidden"/>
```

Notice the `style="visibility: hidden"`. From than on you can have `onClick` handlers on your Previous and Next buttons which just set the visibility of the two images.

```
clickHandlerPrev() {
    document.querySelector("#front-image").style.visibility = "";
    document.querySelector("#back-image").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

clickHandlerNext() {
    document.querySelector("#front-image").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.querySelector("#back-image").style.visibility = "";
}
```

Then your buttons would look like this

```
<a href="#" class="sliderBtnPrev" onclick="clickHandlerPrev">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="sliderBtnNext" onclick="clickHandlerNext">Next</a>
```

Though if I'm getting your goal right, I think your buttons are better named simply "Front cover" and "Back cover" since you're not iterating over lots of images, but switching just those two.